# Javascript event deadlock?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have two event bind to the same click event.

```
button.addEventListener('click', uploadFile);
button.addEventListener('click', showProgress);
```

In `uploadFile` method have code like this:

```
$("#menu2").show() //called after get response from server
```

In `showProgress` method have code like this:

```
while(!$("#menu2").is(":visible")) {
}            // thie is a infinite loop until menu2 show up.
```

I can't figure out any problems here, but my browser crashed.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Or is there any other way to do this, I want to do something until another is completed.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Of course such a while loop is going to “crash” the browser, that is to be expected. _“Is there any way to solve this problem?”_ - what actual problem do you want to solve here in the first place? Showing code that makes little sense, most often does not explain what you actually want to achieve. Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [async.series](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#series) function in the Async library.

> `series(tasks, callbackopt)` 
>   Run the functions in the tasks collection in series, each one running
>   once the previous function has completed.

```
async.series([
        function(callback) {
            // do some stuff ...
            callback(null, 'one');
        },
        function(callback) {
            // do some more stuff ...
            callback(null, 'two');
        }
    ],
    // optional callback
    function(err, results) {
        // results is now equal to ['one', 'two']
    });
```